# How to change the y-axis scale in Nvd3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I am new in *nvd3*.
How can I edit the y-axis scale.

I saw in another question a method-call like this:

`chart.yDomain([0, 15]);`

But that did not work.

My current code looks like this:

```js
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.Einzelkanzlei_Wp:
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.GbR_Wp:
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.PartG_Wp:
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.GmbHCoKG_WP:
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.KG_WP:
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.GmbH_WP:
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.AG_WP:
case $scope.dataService.rechtsformen.PartG_mbB_WP:
    var result = dicErgebnisService.berechneFall2(
        daten.deckungssummeJeJahr1,
        daten.deckungssummeJeFall2,
        daten.deckungsumfangUnmaximiert,
        daten.deckungssummeJeFall1,
        daten.unmaximiertBetrag
    );

    options.chart.type = 'multiChart';
    options.chart.yAxis1.ticks = 8;
    options.chart.xAxis.tickFormat = function(d) {
        return (d+1);
    };
    options.chart.yAxis1.tickFormat = function(d) {
        return $filter('currency')(d, '€', 0);
    };
    options.chart.callback = function(chart) {
        chart.bars1.stacked(true);
        chart.bars2.stacked(true);
        chart.update();
        $scope.setMultiBarValue(chart, options.chart, null, options.chart.stacked);
    };
    return result;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. when you use the ***stackedbarchart***, you have to use `chart.ydomain1([])`.